# Reversing/Sort in a print statement

Tags: python, sorting, reverse

I am trying to sort the output of `list2` in print.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [40, 50, 60]

list3 = list2 + list1 + list2.sort(reverse=True)       

print(f"The new list is: {list3}")
```

I am trying to create for `list3` with a single Python statement that only uses `list1` and `list2` to construct a new `list3` so that the code will print the following output ran.

`The new list is: [40, 50, 60, 1, 2, 3, 60, 50, 40]`

However, I recieve an error:
`TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list`

Edit: Changed `list2.sort(reverse.True)` to `list2.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: `list2.sort(reverse.True)` is an in-place operation, which returns `None`. Use `sorted` instead. Also, you probably mean `reverse=True`

Comment: Can you deduce anything if i point you towards the documentation for the [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method?

Comment: @yatu Yeah, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list3 = list2 + list1 + list2.sort(reverse.True)` throws `Syntax Error` - you probably mean: `list3 = list2 + list1 + list2.sort(reverse = True)`.

[TIP] Easier way than `list2.sort(reverse = True)` is `list2.reverse()`.

However, both (`list2.sort(reverse = True)` and `list2.reverse()`) are [in-place](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/inplace-operator-in-python) operations - they aren't list objects but only operations which changing the list.

To be able to sum the lists, you have to add list objects, for example: `list2[::-1]`:

```py
list3 = list2 + list1 + list2[::-1]
```

Comment: In a way, this is a better solution than solving the op's misuse of `.sort` (although an ideal answer would suggest both solutions and the difference between them).

Comment: It worked, but why? Can I be pointed to a documentation?  Python's official documentation is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: This is list slicing. Thank to this, you can choose parts of list you want to get by using indexes: `your_list[starting index:ending index:periodicity ("-" means reversion)]`. I've kinda messed up this. Look for documentation: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html

Answer (score 2):

As `list2.sort(reverse.True)` sorts `list2` inplace and returns `None` you can not concatenate it to `list2 + list1`

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [40, 50, 60]

list3 = list2 + list1 + sorted(list2, reverse=True)   

print(f"The new list is: {list3}")
```

Works using `sorted` which returns the sorted list

### In-place Sorting:

```
list1 = [2, 3, 1]
list1.sort()
print(list1)
>> [1, 2, 3]
```

### Out-of-Place Sorting:

```
list1 = [2, 3, 1]
result_list = sorted(list1)
print(list1)
>> [2, 3, 1]
print(result_list)
>> [1, 2, 3]
```

Check out https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html for further Information. It gives a brief Introduction.

Comment: It worked, but why? Can I be pointed to a documentation? Python's official documentation is a bit confusing to me

Comment: I edited my answer and inserted the official sorting introduction from Python, if you have Questions concerning this introduction, don't hesitate to ask

Comment: @DaeshaunKMorrison I also added 2 Examples for in-place and out-of-place Sorting, I hope it helps you understanding

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [40, 50, 60]

list3 = list2.copy()
list3.sort(reverse=True)
list4 = list2 + list1 + list3

print(f"The new list is: {list4}")
```